Monitor delay for updating index on deletion
I'm aware than adding / removing data to a table that has one or more index can slow down the operation.
However, I'm wondering how I could monitor that (on postgresql).
When I delete data in one table, it cascade to other large tables, I'd like to know why it is slow. I need to see the details of the deletion delays.
I suspect that the update of the indexes can be the cause but I'd like to see that in monitoring / logs.
Is there a metric or a flag to get such information ?
Thanks in advance
M.

Perhaps running EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) would be a good start.

My guess is that you are not observing index overhead, but the effect of a missing index.
